# Status 404 on valid rewrite, index handler expected

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

The `location /` have a `@rewriteIt` but something is worg...

Fresh installation of NGINX into UBUNTU 16 LTS, all `apt` standard.

NGINX is ignoring my rewrite, why?  how to fix for `example.com/foo` redirect to `test.php`?

Testing status and dynamic pages, all fine except the rewrite:

- OK http://example.com
- BUG (is not for 404) http://example.com/foo
- OK http://example.com/?foo
- OK http://example.com/index.php
- OK http://example.com/test.php

With scripts

### example.com

```
server {
        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        root /var/www/example.com/;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {   # ignoring here?
                try_files $uri $uri/ @rewriteIt =404;
        }

        location  @rewriteIt {  # something wrong here?
                rewrite ^/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$    test.php?obj=$1            last;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
          include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

Same when change to `try_files $uri $uri/ @rewriteIt;`.

### default

```
server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name localhost;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
           include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The named location needs to be the last parameter of the `try_files` statement, replacing the `=404` term. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

There is also a second error. All URIs in `nginx` begin with a leading `/`, so the `rewrite` statement should specify `/test.php?obj=$1` as the target.

Comment: Hi, see my comment "Same when change to", but second error seems ok, I am checking...

Comment: Thanks Richard, now is running!  And, yes, we need to change the two things, not only the first, to work fine.